# Is `reinterpret_cast` to go from derived -> memory -> base safe given the proper static assertions?

Tags: c++, serialization, reinterpret-cast, memory-layout

I'm writing C++14 code which needs to deserialize objects as fast as possible.

The serialization is in memory and occurs in the same process as the deserialization.

Consider this:

```
struct Base
{
    Base(const int a) :
        a {a}
    {
    }

    int a;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived(const int a, const int b, const int c) :
        Base {a},
        b {b},
        c {c}
    {
    }

    int b;
    int c;
};
```

**Assume all those objects will only contain `int` members.**

What I'd like is for some memory region to contain contiguous memory representations of those objects, for example:

```
[Base] [Base] [Derived] [Base] [Derived] [Derived]
```

Let's just pretend you may know if it's `Derived` or not from the `Base::a` member.

Is the following code safe given the two static assertions?

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base
{
    Base(const int a) :
        a {a}
    {
    }

    int a;
};

struct Derived : public Base
{
    Derived(const int a, const int b, const int c) :
        Base {a},
        b {b},
        c {c}
    {
    }

    int b;
    int c;
};

static_assert(alignof(Derived) == alignof(Base),
              "`Base` and `Derived` share the same alignment");

static_assert(sizeof(Derived) == sizeof(Base) + 2 * sizeof(int),
              "Size of `Derived` is expected");

int main()
{
    const Derived d {1, 2, 3};
    const auto dP = reinterpret_cast<const int *>(&d);
    auto& base = reinterpret_cast<const Base&>(*dP);

    std::cout << base.a << std::endl;
}
```

Then the memory region would simply be an `std::vector<int>`, for example.

I know I'm assuming some compiler-specific stuff here and those two `reinterpret_cast` are probably unsafe and not portable, but I'd like to protect my code with good static assertions. Am I missing any?

Comment: This looks like a reimplementation of [flatbuffers](https://github.com/google/flatbuffers), which offer zero-overhead deserialization of objects from "flat" memory. From the summary: *It allows you to directly access serialized data without parsing/unpacking it first, while still having great forwards/backwards compatibility.*

Comment: I was trying to make sense of *"derived -> memory -> base"* in your title. (It reads like your objects are somehow not contained in the computer's memory.) If I understand your question, *"derived -> first member -> base"* could be more accurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Derived` is not a standard layout class. The layout doesn't have the guarantees you expect. In particular, even if `sizeof(Derived) == sizeof(Base) + sizeof(int[2])`, the `Base` subobject could be *after* the members (or inbetween), not that any compiler actually does this.

If this assertion passes:

```cpp
static_assert(offsetof(Derived, Base::a) == 0, "Base::a not at beginning of Derived");
```

(And an implicit `offsetof(Base, a) == 0`, but this is guaranteed because `std::is_standard_layout_v<Base>`)

Then you know your pointers will have the correct addresses (and the fact that `(void*) &d.a`, `(void*) &d` and `(void*) &(Base&) d` will all be equal)

In C++14, this is enough and your `reinterpret_cast`s will work as-is.

---

In C++17, you would have to launder your pointers:

```cpp
const auto *dP = std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const int *>(&d));  // Points to d.Base::a
auto& base = reinterpret_cast<const Base&>(*dP);  // pointer-interconvertible with first member of standard layout class

// Or
const auto *dP = reinterpret_cast<const int *>(&d);  // Points to d, not d.a, but has the same address
auto& base = *std::launder(reinterpret_cast<const Base *>(dP));

// Or
const auto *dP = &d.a;
auto& base = reinterpret_cast<const Base&>(*dP);
```

So keep this in mind if you ever upgrade.

Comment: Thanks! Would a second level of inheritance make the result of another `offsetof()` undefined? For example, `offsetof(EvenMoreDerived, Derived::c)`. I'm reading "_If **type** is not a standard-layout type, the result of **offsetof** is undefined_"...

Comment: @eepp Most compilers will allow `offsetof` to work as an extension for non-standard layout types. In C++17, the wording was changed to ["Use of the `offsetof` macro with a *type* other than a standard-layout class is conditionally-supported."](https://eel.is/c++draft/support.types.layout#1.sentence-2) to bless this extension. It should work no matter how many levels of inheritance you have on all modern compilers.

Comment: In my real implementation, `Base::a` would be private, making `offsetof(Derived, Base::a)` not working. Is there am easy way around that?

Comment: @eepp At that point I would just give up, since this is almost certainly going to be guaranteed by whatever C++ ABI you have (no sane ABI would put padding before the first base class or put the base class not at the beginning with non-virtual inheritance). However, most implementations would accept this if it's in a friend function: https://godbolt.org/z/EafKT5EqT